# Is the series $\frac{\sin (an)}{\ln(n+1)}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $\displaystyle \sum\frac{\sin (an)}{\ln{(n+1)}}$ convergent? ( $a\in \mathbb{R}$ )

I know that $\displaystyle \sum\frac{1}{\ln{n}}$ diverges. I am trying to use the comparison test but fails to come up with a good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ converges for every $x$ whenever $a_n$ decreases to $0$. This is proved in books on Fourier series using the idea of 'summation by parts'. Ref.: See p. 112 of Fourier Series' by Edwards R E.